# Catching specific MAC Address from Paired Devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, pairing

everyone.

new here.

I'm experiencing an issue comparing MAC address from paired devices. I want my app to do something if it finds that a certain MAC address is already paired to it.

Here's part of my java class:

```
Boolean pair_status = false;

Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        if (device.getAddress() == String.valueOf(R.string.BT_MWAddress)) {
            pair_status = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my string initialization:

```
<string name="BT_MWAddress">28:A3:91:E6:A1:50</string>
```

I can see that the device is paired with my phone.

I've tried changing my condition statement to the ones below but I'm still getting the same result.

- `String.valueOf(device.getAddress()) == String.valueOf(R.string.BT_MWAddress)`
- `device.getAddress() == "28:A3:91:E6:A1:50"`
- `String.valueOf(device.getAddress()) == "28:A3:91:E6:A1:50"`
- `String.valueOf(device.getAddress()) == "28:A3:91:E6:A1:50"`

Another check I did is changing my code like below for troubleshooting. and `pair_status` always updates to `-1`. Posted the `pair_status` in a TextView.

```
int pair_status = 0;

Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        if (device.getAddress() == String.valueOf(R.string.BT_MWAddress)) {
            pair_status = 1;
        } else {
            pair_status = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you print all bonded Devices to your terminal, does your device and it's mac address appear in the output?

Comment: yep. it appears there. the `String.valueOf()` was changing my string to some int value of the string resource. also, as a precautionary measures for future statue, I did as Matthew suggested and am using the `.equals()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java, so `==` will compare memory locations. You could try using the `.equals` method, which would compare the actual characters in the string instead of the memory location.

If that doesn't work, can you put print outs for the 2 addresses.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew!

Additional to the `.equals`, your suggestion helped me catch another issue. `String.valueOf()` is messing up my string resource value. I switched to `getResources().getString()` and it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help! This was my first stack overflow answer! :)

Comment: cheers, brother!